# SQL CASE WHEN for multiple values in multiple columns

Tags: sql, list, amazon-web-services, select, presto

I have looked at other questions which might be similar to this but the problem I'm facing is a bit different and I couldn't find any methods for what I'm trying to do.

I have two columns, brand & category. I have to assign a value for the customer id based on the values of either brand or category whichever fits for the role.

Below is my code -

```
CREATE TABLE database.customer_audience_labeled
AS
select m.cust_id, CASE 
                WHEN (m.category IN ('cat_1','cat_2') OR m.brand_id IN ('brand_1','brand_2')) THEN "Sports_Enthusiast"
                WHEN (m.category IN ('cat_4','cat_5') OR m.brand_id IN ('brand_3')) THEN  "Jewellery_Shoppers"
                WHEN (m.category IN ('cat_7') OR m.brand_id IN ('brand_4','brand_5')) THEN  "Movie_Goers"
                ELSE "Others"
            END AS Custom_Audience
FROM customer_table m
GROUP BY 1
```

I am doing this in Athena (Presto DB) and I'm getting the following error -

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 6:702: Column 'gym_goers' cannot be resolved. You may need to manually clean the data at location 's3://aws....'
```

[image: Snapshot of a Sample Table attached here]

Comment: The second column is not part of the aggregation.  It is quite unclear wha  you want to do.   Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would help.

Comment: I see `Custom_Audience` in SQL and `custom_audience_brand` in error message. Typo?

Comment: yeah actually i copied earlier error - this is the error `SYNTAX_ERROR: line 6:702: Column 'gym_goers' cannot be resolved.`

Comment: @GordonLinoff - just attached a sample image for the data and what I'm trying to solve

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you just want:

```
CREATE TABLE database.customer_audience_labeled AS
    SELECT m.cust_id,
           (CASE WHEN (m.category IN ('cat_1','cat_2') OR m.brand_id IN ('brand_1','brand_2')) THEN 'Sports_Enthusiast'
                 WHEN (m.category IN ('cat_4','cat_5') OR m.brand_id IN ('brand_3')) THEN  'Jewellery_Shoppers'
                 WHEN (m.category IN ('cat_7') OR m.brand_id IN ('brand_4','brand_5')) THEN  'Movie_Goers'
                 ELSE 'Others'
            END) AS Custom_Audience
    FROM customer_table m
    GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Also note the use of single quotes for the string constants rather than double quotes.

Comment: I'm getting the following error message - `no viable alternative at input`

Comment: @lightyagami96 . . . That is odd.  This query is not using keywords and does not have data type conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the reason is, but OR statement wasn't working.

I removed OR statement and moved them into the additional WHEN statement and its giving me the results.

```
    CREATE TABLE database.customer_audience_labeled AS
        SELECT m.cust_id,
               CASE WHEN m.category IN ('cat_1','cat_2') THEN 'Sports_Enthusiast'
                    WHEN m.brand_id IN ('brand_1','brand_2') THEN 'Sports_Enthusiast'
                    WHEN m.category IN ('cat_4','cat_5') THEN 'Jewellery_Shoppers'
                    WHEN m.brand_id IN ('brand_3') THEN 'Jewellery_Shoppers'
                    WHEN m.category IN ('cat_7') THEN 'Movie_Goers' 
                    WHEN m.brand_id IN ('brand_4','brand_5') THEN 'Movie_Goers'
                    ELSE 'Others'
                    END AS Custom_Audience
    FROM customer_table m
    GROUP BY 1, 2;
```